# Caching DAL return objects?

Tags: c#, caching, sql-server-express, data-access-layer

I was wondering if i should be caching the objects returned from my DAL in some way? I may have multiple UI controls calling for the same data in a single load of the page.

What would you guys recommend? Am i begin a little to cautious? Its not a terrible amount of data. But if i should be caching in some way, what would be the recommended approach?

Comment: You need to cache if you have performance problems and not because someone says so...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I disagree. You can watch out for the future, and not needlessly do 20 calls to get a UserID for example. He could also be overloading the database and not know it, but not have performance problems on his side.

Comment: Well i have been running into some strange performance issues, but i am not yet convinced that it is due to the multiple calls to the DB. When debugging the grabbing of the data take milliseconds. But it is on the list is am eliminating. However, as you said Yuriy, it does not hurt to plan for the future in terms of the calls to the DB.

Comment: That all said, what would be the best way to cache the objects being sent out of my DAL?

Comment: You can give [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html?topDT) a shot to see where your bottleneck is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [cache](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2010/09/15/caching-an-asp-net-page.aspx) AND if you really have multiple controls on the same page using the same data you can call the data once in the parent page and pass a reference to it to each control with a Setter in each control (rather than have each control pull the same data from the DAL themselves), eg:

```
myControl.AllUsers = _allUsers;
....
myOtherControl.AllUsers = _allUsers;
```

I also agree with @DanielHilgarth. Caching adds complexity (when to refresh the cache, for example). If the page loads quickly anyway, I wouldn't bother.

If the page is slow, database calls in loops are often the culprit in my experience.

Comment: thanks this is the aproach i am going to take, it seems to be working very well. I'm going to call the data once from the parent page (and cache it on the parent page if i need to later) and pass the filled object to all the controls rather than having the controls call them independently. I think this will optimize the page considerably and allow me to avoid some complexity of having to cache inside the DAL.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if it's safe and nescessary to do so.  If the data you are working with does not require realtime data (ie. your blog) then by all means cache if you feel it's nescessary to do so (meaning your site is running slow).

A problem with caching that a lot of times people forget to account for is being able to clear the cache on demand if something that requires an immediate response (for example you ban a user, or update payment gateway information).

There are two main types of caching, sliding cache and fixed-time cache.

Sliding cache (cache that gets extended each time a valid retrieval is performed) is great for resources that have relatively easy to compute values, but may suffer from database / network overhead.  Cache for 1 hour (or w/ever) on a sliding cache, and then manually invalidate (remove) the cache whenever an INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE occurs for the DAO.  This way the user will see realtime results, but will infact be cached whenever possible.

Fixed time cache is great for resources that are difficult to perform (ie a very complex stored procedure) and do not require realtime accuracy.  Cache for 1 hour (or w/ever) for the first time it's requested, and do not clear cache until that first hour is up.  INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE is ignored by your cache mechanism (unless it's absolutely nescesssary).

Comment: Thanks Mathew. This would literally be a maybe 5 second cache. It is real time data i am working with, but my big concern is one single page calling for the data maybe 10 times. If i can cache the first response for a few seconds, then all subsequent calls for the data by the same page would be much quicker, and the DB would only have to handle 1 call for the data.

Comment: Is it one single page ~request~?  If so, just save it in a local variable and reuse the variable if the data is supposed to be constant.  Regardless, the sliding cache mechanism would be best for this if you still want to implement some sort of caching.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you can look at this library:

http://www.reactiveui.net/

it provides a neat an clean way to cache your objects.

I'd say it is a very neat way.